# Log all cURL requests from an PHP application with third-party libraries

Tags: php, curl, dll, yii2

Alright, I'm having a tough time in my PHP Yii2 application. I need to log every incoming and outgoing requests from my application. Incomming requests can be easily logged in PHP itself (adding some handler in bootstrap stage), that is easy.

But the real problem is I'm using many third-party libraries (i.e. Amazon MWS SDK, Ebay SDK, some Guzzle requests, etc) and I want to log all outgoing requests with error response (for debug/analyze reasons).

Is it even possible to change some settings in curl, to log those requests? I mean does curl support some settings in `php.ini` `[curl]` for logging stuff.. Or if not, is there sources for `php_curl.dll` that you can make some changes to write logs, and compile it.. Or at least add some handler for all curl request in application without changing/copying the third-party SDKs.

I've searched for this issue, and found a solution like `tcpdump` or wireshark to sniff some packets, but is there really no solution in `curl` side to implement a logging?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: You should use audit trail extension of Yii2 framework, It will help you display all logs
https://github.com/bedezign/yii2-audit

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't set it in .ini

But if you can edit your php curl-run code, you can use two two oprions CURLOPT_VERBOSE and CURLOPT_STDERR

http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

CURLOPT_VERBOSE - turn on showing verbose information.
CURLOPT_STDERR - output handle for log

So you code will be something like

```
$LogFileHandle = fopen($PathToLog."/cur.log", "a+");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $LogFileHandle);
```

Where *$ch* -  cURL handle returned by curl_init. And *$PathToLog* - path to directory with log like *"/var/log"*

Comment: Yes, I understand, but in my code I make many requests (from different places), including sdk's (which are located in `vendor`), so I cannot change their source code..